# How to show search result in a list view as dropdown of SearchView?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-widget, searchview

I'm using `SearchView` widget. I want to show my search result as listview as dropdown of `SearchView`. Just like this
[image: search view]

Here is my code. My searched result is in `searchedList`.

```java
    private List<BookLight> searchedList=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu,@NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.group_timeline_menu,menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_book_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                readData(query);
                Log.i(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit: "+query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,menuInflater);
    }

    private void readData(String queryData){
        Query query=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("GroupMembersBooks")
                .child(groupDetails.getGroupID())
                .child("books")
                .orderByChild("bookName")
                .startAt(queryData)
                .limitToFirst(4);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot childSnapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    BookLight bookLight=childSnapShot.getValue(BookLight.class);
                    searchedList.add(bookLight);
                    Log.i(TAG, "readData: "+bookLight.getBookName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: @AlexMamo code has no problem. But don't know how to proceed further for my desired result.